# How can I programatically keep track of number of certificate warnings in browser?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, firefox, browser-extensions, plugins

I want to keep a count of how many certificate warnings have been made in the browser over a period of several weeks. I also want to keep track of whether the user ignored these warnings and just clicked through them. Any ideas on how I could do this? Any plugin out there which extracts such statistics from a web browsing session?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of a easy browser add on but there are web content inspection systems that should be able to count this for you in logs. You would then consolidate and perform counts on the logs if it's not native in reporting. Alternatively, you could group policy something like [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648706(v=vs.85).aspx) logging on each individual system in a spool and then you could extract based on error codes.

Comment: any example of web content inspection systems?

Comment: are you referring to deep packet inspection? Would this not be overkill? Can one not get this information without such a complex approach?

Comment: WinHTTP logging is just that; so it's not DPI because windows is spooling this information for you as it gets pushed out. web content inspection devices *may* be DPI depending on your definition but really it's the honestly the easiest method to capture what you're asking in our opinion.